# Use an image as the UITableView separator

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, uiimage, uicolor

I got an UITableView on my project and I need to customize the separator. I want to use an image instead of a color. I tried using the +colorWithPatternImage: UIColor method with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. What you can do however is to set the separator to none and then add the image you want to use as a separator to the cell view.

Comment: Ended up using your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I could use some help here :) When implementing this solution, how did you solve the problem of the row selected? I'm noticing that the selected color applies to it too :(

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking? In general you can control if the default row selection animation is used or not. Also you can adjust the separator image (like using or not using transparency) which will change the row selection default animation.

Answer (score 34):

use this code i use it in my application this will work

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"]];
[self.tableview setSeparatorColor:color];
```

Comment: i've read bad things about [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] relation with memory